# Datetime.ParseExact is not working

Tags: c#

This may be one of those stupid, I missed something errors but here it goes.

I have a date time in string format (no trailing or leading whitespaces)

```
Sun 27 Apr 2013 7:30pm
```

I use this code to turn it into a DateTime variable but it always returns false

```
DateTime date; 
bool dateParsed = false;   

CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

dateParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(when, "ddd d MMM yyyy h:mmtt", provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);
```

Hopefully someone can quickly tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I think this "ddd d MMM yyyy h:mmtt" is not correct. The day is two digits and it should be "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mmtt". Just try this to see if it works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because April 27th, 2013 fell on a Saturday, not on a Sunday. If you try to parse

```
Sat 27 Apr 2013 7:30pm
```

It should work. You can see that by printing out the date using the same format, and comparing it with what you're trying to parse.

```
bool dateParsed = false;
DateTime date;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string when = "Sat 27 Apr 2013 7:30pm";
dateParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(when, "ddd d MMM yyyy h:mmtt", provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);
Console.WriteLine(date);
date = new DateTime(2013, 4, 27, 19, 30, 00, DateTimeKind.Local);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("ddd d MMM yyyy h:mmtt", provider));
```

Comment: Yep, just figured this out when I tried to see what the exception was saying. I should have known not to trust my data source :|

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to use `ParseExact` instead. It gives you the exact problem by crashing with an exception:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect.
```

April 27 2013 is a Saturday, not a Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your date, which is invalid.  Change it like

```
Sat 27 Apr 2013 7:30pm
```

Check this screenshot,

[image]

Here is your code:

```
DateTime date;
bool dateParsed = false;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string when = "Sat 27 Apr 2013 7:30pm";
dateParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(when, "ddd d MMM yyyy h:mmtt", provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Oh, Your right.  Sorry for that.  I will update it.